# How to write a 'count' for buttons using e.getSource()?

Tags: java, swing, button

I'm not sure how to write this line of code correctly, but what I'm trying to get is,  " if the count of the `e.getSource` is 1, set it to 0".

Would that be written as:

```
if (count.(e.getSource()) == 1)
{
    count = 0;   
}
```

What would be the correct way of writing `count.(e.getSource())` ?

Comment: What do you want to count? Can you elaborate `if the count of the e.getSource is 1` ?

Comment: The number of times the anonomuos(no name) button is clicked. That is why I have the e.getSource().

Comment: If the count of the button I clicked on is '1' then reset it to 0.

Comment: The button itself will not keep track how many times has it been clicked. You can declare a variable in the class to store the number of times it was clicked.

Comment: What is the return type of the getSource() method?

Comment: That is why I **tried** to write, "count.(e.getSource())" or the count of the button I clicked.

Comment: I did declare a variable, everything is taking care of, I just want to find out how to do this correctly.

Comment: The getSource() method returns the object/component I'm using my actionevent on.

Comment: @D.Maximov Then it has nothing to do with `e.getSource()`. Just use a normal `int` variable.

Comment: Why would I use an int? I have buttons that the user created during runtime, when he clicks on them I want each button to keep track of its counts, that is why I'm using e.getSource().

Comment: create a variable and increment it by 1 every time you come on actionevent click. Then check the value of variable

Comment: I got the tracking of the counts, I need help with the e.getSource() method. Since the buttons, that are created during runtime, could be any name.

Comment: @D.Maximov Take a look at both solutions and let me know whether it works for you.

Comment: `count.(e.getSource())` will never be valid java. You should paste your complete action listener code. Then somebody can tell you where to declare count, and how to increment it. You do not need to use e.getSource() unless you are using the same action listener for all of your buttons (which you shouldn't be doing but that is an aside.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To illustrate the point where you do not need a variable name to access the instance of the button being clicked. Take a look at this working example:

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class CountClicks{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Counting individual clicks");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new DrawingSpace());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);                 
            }
        }); 
    }
}
```

Your customized Button class:

```
class MyButton extends JButton
{
    private int numOfClicks;    //Add additional property for JButton

    public MyButton(String name){
        super(name);
        numOfClicks = 0;        
    }

    public int getClicks(){
        return numOfClicks;
    }

    public void setClicks(int clicks){
        this.numOfClicks = clicks;
    }    
}
```

A container to contain your components for testing:

```
class DrawingSpace extends JPanel
{
    private MyButton[] btn;
    private JLabel lblDisplay;   
    public DrawingSpace(){      
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450, 100));
        init();
    }

    private void init(){
        btn = new MyButton[5];
        ButtonHandler bh = new ButtonHandler();
        for(int x=0; x<btn.length; x++){
            btn[x] = new MyButton("Button " + (x+1));
            btn[x].addActionListener(bh);
            add(btn[x]);
        }
        lblDisplay = new JLabel("Watch here..");
        add(lblDisplay);
    }

    private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener{
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            MyButton myBtn = (MyButton)e.getSource();
            myBtn.setClicks(myBtn.getClicks()+ 1);
            lblDisplay.setText(myBtn.getText() + " was clicked, it has gathered " + myBtn.getClicks() + " so far.");   
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this helped so much!

Answer (score 2):

`e.getSource` returns the ***object*** on which the Event initially occurred. You can get the JButton which triggers the event by casting it:

```
((JButton)e.getSource())
```

However, the button itself will not keep track of the number of times it has been clicked. You can just declare a variable to keep track of the clicks.

```
class DrawingSpace extends JPanel
{
    private JButton btn;
    private int count;

    public DrawingSpace(){
        count = 0;
        btn = new JButton("Click me");
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                if (count == 1)
                    count = 0;    
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but none of my buttons have names, the user of the program makes them during run time, if my buttons had names, like in your program then I would be able to do this. But my buttons have no names.

Comment: @D.Maximov Take a look at the other solution below.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution if you want each Button to remembers how many times it has been clicked, you may create a customized JButton:

```
class MyButton extends JButton
{
    private int numOfClicks;    //Add additional property for JButton

    public MyButton(String name){
        super(name);
        numOfClicks = 0;        
    }

    public int getClicks(){
        return numOfClicks;
    }

    public void setClicks(int clicks){
        this.numOfClicks = clicks;
    }    
}
```

Now each of your customized buttons can remember the number of times each of them is being clicked:

```
class DrawingSpace extends JPanel
{
    private MyButton btn;   
    public DrawingSpace(){
        btn = new MyButton("Click me");
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                MyButton myBtn = (MyButton)e.getSource();
                if (myBtn.getClicks() == 1)
                    myBtn.setClicks(0);    
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What if you had multiple buttons in your program and none of them had a name? How would you tell which was was clicked, **and** tell how many counts it has?

Comment: @D.Maximov `How would you tell which was was clicked` It can. By using `e.getSource` and cast it to a `MyButton` you will get the instance of the button which was clicked. All buttons can now record how times they themselves has been clicked so far. So if you have 20 buttons, there can be 20 different records for number of clicks. ***Take note that***, the `numOfClicks` resides in `MyButton` class.

Comment: How would you test your program? There's no main method. So I could get  a visual. Thanks!

Comment: @D.Maximov Just create a `main` and add DrawingSpace into the `JFrame`. Give me a sec.

Comment: It says that you can't convert JButton to MyButton. Is there supposed to be something else?